# Listview Update not workng

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to change the Select Command my DataSource uses using a dropdownlist. When the page loads it sets the select command depending on the selected index. When I change the dropdownlist the page refreshes but the data doesn't! Where am I going wrong?

**.aspx file**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="filmFilter" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="filmFilter_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Filter</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="priceASC">Price: Low-High</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="priceDSC">Price: High-Low</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringFilms %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="filmID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <ItemTemplate>
    ...    
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
    ...
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**code-behind - page load:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (filmFilter.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [films]";
        }
        if (filmFilter.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [films] ORDER BY [filmPrice]";
        }
        if (filmFilter.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [films] ORDER BY [filmPrice] DESC";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put `SelectCommand` changing code inside `filmFilter_SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: Yeah that works cheers, so simple its annoying!

Answer (score 2):

You've got it so your datasource is set on the page_load which is fine but you've wrapped it in

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
```

Which means your code to change the datasource will only happen when you are not in postback (when you change the value of the dropdown you will be in a postback)

Have a read through
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx
It will help with your understanding